# Plotting a 1D dot plot in SAS

Tags: plot, graph, sas

[image]

Hello, I would like to plot something that is close to this but
I cannot seem to get it.

I have the data

```
data table2_1;
```

`input Modified_Mortar Unmodifided_Mortar;
cards;
16.85 16.62
16.40 16.75
17.21 17.37
16.35 17.12
16.52 16.98
17.04 16.87
16.96 17.34
17.15 17.02
16.59 17.08
16.57 17.27
;
run;`

And I tried

`proc freq data=table2_1;
 tables Modified_Mortar / plots=freqplot (type=dotplot);
 tables Unmodifided_Mortar / plots=freqplot (type=dotplot);
run;`

but it gave me an unnecessarily huge plot which was spaced equally and cannot compare the two distributions as I intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around a bit with `sgplot` and this is the closest I could come up with. It's not exact, but with a little fiddling in an image editor you can pretty much get it.

[image]

```
data table2_1;
input Modified_Mortar Unmodifided_Mortar;
retain mod_line 0.75 unmod_line 0;
cards;
16.85 16.62
16.40 16.75
17.21 17.37
16.35 17.12
16.52 16.98
17.04 16.87
16.96 17.34
17.15 17.02
16.59 17.08
16.57 17.27
;
run;

proc sgplot data=table2_1;
    label Modified_Mortar = 'Strength (kgf/cm squared)';

    scatter x = Modified_Mortar    y=mod_line   / markerattrs=(symbol=circlefilled color=black size=10);
    scatter x = Unmodifided_Mortar y=unmod_line / markerattrs=(symbol=circlefilled color=bib size=10);

    refline -0.25 / axis=y lineattrs=(color=bib thickness=2) name='mod' legendlabel='Unmodified' ;
    refline 0.5 / axis=y lineattrs=(color=black thickness=2) name='unmod' legendlabel='Modified';

    yaxis display=(nolabel) min=-0.25 max=15;
    xaxis values=(16.24 to 17.50 by 0.14) min=16.30 max=17.40 valueattrs=(size=12) labelattrs=(size=12);

    keylegend 'mod' 'unmod' / location=outside position=bottom valueattrs=(size=12);
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach that uses the data in a treatment:response categorical form.  A labeled triangle marker is used to show the mean (triangle apex being the balance point)

[image]

```
data have;
  treatment = 'Modified  '; y=1.13; input response @; output;
  treatment = 'Unmodified'; y=0.13; input response;   output;

  attrib
    response label = "Strength (kgf/cm2)"
  ;

cards;
16.85 16.62
16.40 16.75
17.21 17.37
16.35 17.12
16.52 16.98
17.04 16.87
16.96 17.34
17.15 17.02
16.59 17.08
16.57 17.27
;
run;

proc sql;
  create table plot as 
  select * from have
  outer union corresponding
  select 
    treatment,
    case treatment
      when ('Unmodified') then -0.15
      when ('Modified  ') then  0.85
      else 0
    end as y2,
    mean(response) as mean format=5.2
  from have
  group by treatment;
quit;


ods proclabel "Concrete dot plot";

ods graphics / height=220px width=800px;

proc sgplot data=plot description="Response to treatment";
  title "Concrete strength response to treatment";

  scatter 
    x=response y=y
    / markerattrs=(symbol=circlefilled color=black size=12px)      
  ;

  scatter 
    x=mean y=y2
    / datalabel=mean
      datalabelpos=bottom
      markerattrs=(symbol=triangle color=black size=12px)
  ;

  keylegend
    / exclude = ("y" "y2")
  ;

  yaxis 
    offsetmin = 0.2
    values = ( 0 1 2 )
    valuesdisplay = ( "Unmodified" "Modified" " " )
    display = ( noticks nolabel )
    colorbands = odd 
  ;

  xaxis 
    grid 
  ;

  refline  0.00 ;
  refline  1.00 ;

run;

title;
footnote;
```

Comment: This is a really great answer.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, maybe a **box plot** would be more statistically informative and have a wider palette of visualization options.

Comment: Agreed. That was the first thing I thought of as well. From a distribution standpoint, that's where I would go too.